# JS: Получить html редирект ссылки

Tags: javascript

Есть ссылка - "https://example.com".
Если перейти по ней в браузер, она перенаправит нас на https://example2.com а может потом и на https://example3.com. Мне нужно сделать запрос (как следствие получить html) именно на последнюю ссылку. Заранее я их не знаю.
Вариант который **не работает**:

```
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false );
xmlHttp.send( null );
return xmlHttp.responseText;
```

Comment: Вообще говоря, XMLHttpRequest по умолчанию следует по редиректам. Ваша проблема не в этом. Вероятнее всего проблема в чужом домене

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего, CORS не позволит тебе получить адрес.

Но если позволит, то можно так:

```
fetch("https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/818358/178988").then(resp => console.log(resp.url))
```

А лучше использовать head-запрос:

```
fetch("https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/818358/178988", { method: 'head' }).then(resp => console.log(resp.url))
```

Comment: Если позволит, - не будет проблем и с кодом в вопросе

Comment: @vp_arth, код в вопросе получает текст ответа, а не адрес.

Comment: Ну так и весь вопрос просит html, какбэ: `как следствие получить html`

Comment: @vp_arth, ну значит я невнимательно читаю...